# Generic choose of method / infering methods in java

Tags: java, generics, methods, inference

im not experienced at all with generics but I set up a little code.
My goal is to implement `searchData(ResultSet rs)` so that it chooses the correct method corresponding to `data` which is the given class/databaseField name.

Examples:

For `data` = "medium" I want to call `searchMedium(rs)`

For `data` = "customer" I want to call `searchCustomer(rs)`

For `data` = "loan" I want to call `searchLoan(rs)`

I do not want to realize it with if or switch case as this will turn huge for many of those methods.
I hope you can understand my intention and that there is a possibility to realize it.
Here is my code:

```
public class test3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test3 t = new test3();
    ArrayList<?> list = t.search("medium");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}

public <T> ArrayList<T> search(String data) {
    ArrayList<T> resultList = new ArrayList<T>();
    Connection c;
    Statement stmt;
    String sql = "Error occurred before executing SQL statement";
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:library.sqlite");
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        sql = "SELECT * FROM " + data + ";";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        resultList = searchData(rs, data);
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() + "\n" + sql + "\nSQL query for " + data
                + " failed");
    }
    return resultList;
}

private <T> ArrayList<T> searchData(ResultSet rs, String data) {
    ArrayList list = null;
    // TODO ???
    return list;
}

private ArrayList<Loan> searchLoan(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<Loan> resultList = new ArrayList<Loan>();
    Loan match;
    while (rs.next()) {
        int loanNumber = rs.getInt("NUMBER");
        String mediumId = rs.getString("MEDIUMCODE");
        int customerNumber = rs.getInt("CUSTOMERNUMBER");
        String loanDate = rs.getString("LOANDATE");
        String targetReturndate = rs.getString("TARGETRETURNDATE");
        String returnDate = rs.getString("RETURNDATE");
        int extensions = rs.getInt("EXTENSIONS");
        match = new Loan(loanNumber, mediumId, customerNumber, targetReturndate, loanDate, returnDate, extensions);
        resultList.add(match);
    }
    return resultList;
}

private ArrayList<Medium> searchMedium(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<Medium> resultList = new ArrayList<Medium>();
    Medium match;
    while (rs.next()) {
        String number = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("NUMBER"));
        String id = rs.getString("ID");
        String isbn = rs.getString("ISBN");
        String title = rs.getString("TITLE");
        String authors = rs.getString("AUTHORS");
        String type = rs.getString("TYPE");
        String category = rs.getString("CATEGORY");
        String publishingYear = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("PUBLISHINGYEAR"));
        String publishingMonth = rs.getString("PUBLISHINGMONTH");
        String timestamp = rs.getString("TIMESTAMP");
        String loanerNumber = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("LOANERNUMBER"));
        match = new Medium(number, id, isbn, title, type, authors, category, publishingYear, publishingMonth,
                timestamp, loanerNumber);
        resultList.add(match);
    }
    return resultList;
}

private ArrayList<Customer> searchCustomer(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<Customer> resultList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    Customer match;
    while (rs.next()) {
        String number = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("NUMBER"));
        String id = rs.getString("ID");
        String lastname = rs.getString("LASTNAME");
        String firstname = rs.getString("FIRSTNAME");
        String birthdate = rs.getString("BIRTHDATE");
        String zipcode = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("ZIPCODE"));
        String domicile = rs.getString("DOMICILE");
        String street = rs.getString("STREET");
        String housenumber = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("HOUSENUMBER"));
        String notification = rs.getString("NOTIFICATION");
        String notificationTimestamp = rs.getString("NOTIFICATIONTIMESTAMP");
        match = new Customer(number, id, lastname, firstname, birthdate, zipcode, domicile, street, housenumber,
                notification, notificationTimestamp);
        resultList.add(match);
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

}

Probably my approach is a really bad one so I would be very happy for any kind of help/suggestions.

with much thanks

Comment: What's the problem with the `switch`? How many values are you expecting?

Comment: There will be a specific method for every single column in the database so it is easily possible that this will grow to more than one hundred cases.
A real lambda expression like in haskell would fix the problem but is there something corresponding in java? I only know lambdas with functional interfaces from java8 but thats more syntactic sugar...

Comment: Adding a `case` to a `switch` is pretty trivial in comparison to creating a new method.

Comment: You can use reflection to call the method by name, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: The choice is not between switch case and creating a new method. I would have to use switch case to call the new methods I need to create anyway. The question is whether it is necessarry to write that huge switch case as it will become hardly maintainable soon.

Comment: I understand. What I'm saying is if you have hundreds of methods to maintain, the last thing you should worry about is a large `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understand, here you can't use Generics to call methods dynamically. To that you have to use method overloading. If you are willing to give up Generics, then following way can be used.

```
private RestultSet getResultSet(String tblName){
    Connection c;
    Statement stmt;
    String sql = "Error occurred before executing SQL statement";
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:library.sqlite");
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        sql = "SELECT * FROM " + tblName+ ";";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        return rs;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() + "\n" + sql + "\nSQL query for " + data
            + " failed");
    }
}

public ArrayList<Customer> search(Customer c) {
    ArrayList<Customer> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    ResultSet rs = getRestultSet(c.getSimpleName());

    Customer match;
    while (rs.next()) {
        String number = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("NUMBER"));
        String id = rs.getString("ID");
        String lastname = rs.getString("LASTNAME");
        String firstname = rs.getString("FIRSTNAME");
        String birthdate = rs.getString("BIRTHDATE");
        String zipcode = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("ZIPCODE"));
        String domicile = rs.getString("DOMICILE");
        String street = rs.getString("STREET");
        String housenumber = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("HOUSENUMBER"));
        String notification = rs.getString("NOTIFICATION");
        String notificationTimestamp = rs.getString("NOTIFICATIONTIMESTAMP");
        match = new Customer(number, id, lastname, firstname, birthdate,     zipcode, domicile, street, housenumber,
            notification, notificationTimestamp);
        resultList.add(match);
    }

    rs.close();
    return resultList;
}

public ArrayList<Medium> search(Medium m) {
    ArrayList<Medium> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    ResultSet rs = getRestultSet(m.getSimpleName());

    Medium match;
    while (rs.next()) {
        String number = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("NUMBER"));
        String id = rs.getString("ID");
        String isbn = rs.getString("ISBN");
        String title = rs.getString("TITLE");
        String authors = rs.getString("AUTHORS");
        String type = rs.getString("TYPE");
        String category = rs.getString("CATEGORY");
        String publishingYear = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("PUBLISHINGYEAR"));
        String publishingMonth = rs.getString("PUBLISHINGMONTH");
        String timestamp = rs.getString("TIMESTAMP");
        String loanerNumber = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("LOANERNUMBER"));
        match = new Medium(number, id, isbn, title, type, authors, category, publishingYear, publishingMonth,
            timestamp, loanerNumber);
        resultList.add(match);
    }

    rs.close();
    return resultList;
}
```

Likewise you can put search method for Loan also.

The main method is as follows

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test3 t = new test3();
    ArrayList<?> list = t.search(new Medium());
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

Hope this will work... Thanks...

Comment: This does not work because the problem remains, it is just restructured.
Additionally I have to figure out parameters each time I insert a column object into t.search(...) because all those objects are buildt with data given as parameters in the constructor.